# Javascript:drag and drop image upload: prints error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm learning to create a image upload function with the famous tutorial here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

I follow the tutorial carefully step by step, it works perfect till the point of creating a drag and drop function which the drop event triggers the handleFiles function, the console log print error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Where I did wrong?

Here is the code:

```
<!-- tutorial source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications -->
<!-- jquery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/googleapis.js"></script>

<!-- css file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testcss.css">

<!-- display input file -->
<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple id="inputElem" >

<!-- accessing selected file -->
<script>
    // Note: the selectFile can only be access AFTER a event triggered (e.g. onchange)
    var selectedFile = $('#inputElem')[0].files[0];
</script>

<!-- Adding a onchange envent listener to input file -->
<script>
    // Find the input file element
var inputElement = document.getElementById("inputElem");
    // Attach change listener to the element, with a callback function named handlefiles
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
    // declare the handleFiles function
function handleFiles() {
    // when the change event triggered, get the value of the file input
  var fileList = this.files;
    // test
  console.log(fileList);

    // Getting information about selected files 
  var numFiles=fileList.length;
    // test the variable numFile if it has value
  console.log(numFiles);
    // test iterating names
  for (var i = 0, numFiles = fileList.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
  var fileName = fileList[i].name;
  console.log(fileName);
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Create a handmade select file button, the button clicked will yield the same result of clicking the native select filed -->
<!-- display the button -->
<div id="fileSelect">Upload Images</div>
<script>
// find fileSelect (button) and fileElem (input files)
var fileSelect=document.getElementById("fileSelect");
var fileElem=document.getElementById("inputElem");
fileSelect.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(fileElem){
        fileElem.click();
    }

},false);
</script>


<!-- slecting files using drag and drop -->
<!-- display the contenteditable div -->
<div id="topic_content_input" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" data-placeholder="dropbox " ></div>
<script>
var dropbox;
// find dropbox element
dropbox = document.getElementById("topic_content_input");
// attach event listener to dropbox
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
// define the callback function
function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  handleFiles(files);
}
</script>
```

CSS(testcss.css)

```
#inputElem{
    display:none;
}
#fileSelect{
    cursor:pointer;
    width:110px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #ffcc99;
    text-align: center;
    padding:3px;
    color: white;
}

#topic_content_input[data-placeholder]:not(:focus):not([data-div-placeholder-content]):before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2px;
    color: rgba(134,134,134,0.6);
}
/*#adjust{
    display:inline-block;
}*/
#topic_content_input{
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:2px;
    min-height: 100px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width:521px;
    /*display inline in safari creates a big I-Beam cursor, howoever, if remove display=inline, prewrap would stop working*/

  /*position:relative;*/
  /*display:flex;*/
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-radius:3px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#topic_content_input:focus{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color:orange;
  outline-width:0px;
  line-height:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your function to following,

```
function handleFiles(files) {
    // when the change event triggered, get the value of the file input
  var fileList = files;
    // test
  console.log(fileList);

    // Getting information about selected files 
  var numFiles=fileList.length;
    // test the variable numFile if it has value
  console.log(numFiles);
    // test iterating names
  for (var i = 0, numFiles = fileList.length; i < numFiles; i++) {
  var fileName = fileList[i].name;
  console.log(fileName);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it is not working for droping files. The upload images button even prints error when selecting files using the code above.

Comment: Here from my side it is working for dropping files.It shows me length as well as their names.